# Monte Carlo or how to calculate the model several times

Tags: simulation

follow question:

How can I calculate this model several times automatically.

```
Clear[P];
P[t_] := P[t] = P[t - 1] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, RP]];
P[0] = 1;
ListLinePlot[Table[P[t], {t, 1, 20}]]
```

I used `Table[Table[P[t], {t, 1, 10}], {i, 1, 10}]` to calculate this 10 times, but everytime I had the same result.

Thanks

Comment: Do you require the use of `Table`?  Note that once you memoize it, you'll of course keep getting the same result.

Comment: Thanks to all of you
Your advice is realy helpful

Comment: @Alex please do not use answer for comments. Take [**a tour**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to express your gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

As Alan mentions, the fundamental problem is that the memoization assignments assign values to all but p[0] in the first run. When this is eliminated, the OP's method works:

```
Clear[p];

rp = 1;

p[t_] := p[t - 1] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, rp]];

p[0] = 1;

out = Table[p[t], {10}, {t, 1, 10}];

ListLinePlot[out]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`RandomFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomFunction.html) and [`WienerProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WienerProcess.html).

```
rp = 1;
paths = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, rp], {1, 20, 1}, 10]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[paths]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may find the [Random Processes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RandomProcesses.html) guide in the documentation useful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, closest to your approach:

```
rp = 1;
dist = NormalDistribution[0, rp];
Table[
 RecurrenceTable[{a[t + 1] == a[t] + RandomVariate[dist], a[0] == 1}, 
  a, {t, 1, 20}],
 10]
```

Here is another way:

```
shocks = RandomVariate[dist, {10, 20}];
1 + (Accumulate /@ shocks)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

```
f[n_, rp_] := NestList[# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, rp]] &, 1, n]
```

For example:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[f[10, rp], n], Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10}], {n, {10, 20}}, {rp, 1, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]